# iPhone game with Box2d: How to move world around player

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

So I have a very basic iPhone game that I am working on, where a ball moves around the screen, with fixtures for walls that the ball can hit.

I want the game to be side-scrolling from right to left, but I can't figure out how to approach this.

I have done a bit of research and it seems that the best approach is to move the world around the player. So my question is, how do I move/slide the wall fixtures consistently to the left to imitate a side-scrolling effect?

Comment: Is the game always auto-scrolling, or does it respond to some form of touch event?

Comment: Always auto-scrolling :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't move the world. Move the camera. Create a class (camera) that will store its position relative to the world. Using the camera position you can calculate the layer (CCLayer where everything is drawn) position. In the simplest case it will be `-cameraPos`.

Comment: Okay so I tried this and liked the outcome. The only thing is, how would I make bounds around the screen so that the player can't go off screen?

Comment: @Sneaksta: I would make a static body and move it with the camera

Comment: How exactly would I go about that?

Comment: @Sneaksta: create a b2body and add b2ChainShape to form the screen box

Comment: Okay I'll give that a go now!

Comment: I am quite new to this, and I can't seem to find any tutorials or help  regarding creating a b2ChainShape. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Sneaksta: A good starting point is box2d manual http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32080/discussion-between-sneaksta-and-andrew)